# Problem with extracting files with DotNetZip. It doesn't extract files. what's the problem?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetzip

```
private void ZipExtract(string zipfilename)
{
    var path = Server.MapPath(@"~/Files");
    ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(zipfilename);
    zip.ExtractSelectedEntries("name=*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png,*.gif,*.bmp", " ", path,ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
}


[HttpPost]
public ContentResult Uploadify(HttpPostedFileBase filedata)
{
    var path = Server.MapPath(@"~/Files");
    var filePath = Path.Combine(path, filedata.FileName);
    if (filedata.FileName.Contains(".zip"))
    {
        ZipExtract(filedata.FileName);
    }
    filedata.SaveAs(filePath);
}
```

Comment: Try debugging and see whether `"name=*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png,*.gif,*.bmp"` is a valid format or not. try using only one extension `*.jpg` that works

Answer (score 0):

what's the error you see?  Exception?  Other condition?  You need to add some additional context to your question. But there are a couple things that stick out even without a better description.

1. employ a using() clause with the ZipFile class; it is IDisposable.
2. It looks like you try to extract the zip file before you call .SaveAs().  If I read your code correctly, that means the ZipFile.Read() is trying to read a file that has not yet been created. If that is the case it will throw a `FileNotFoundException`. I may be wrong about this; more text from you would help clarify.

Comment: I want my application to upload zip file, extract it and save extracted file in a folder("Files" for example)

Comment: I mean I don't have to create zip file, I must accept zip file as a parameter

Comment: Right, well - if I am reading your code correctly, you are trying to read from a file location before saving data to that file location. If you want to read from the filesystem, You should save the uploaded file before trying to do so.